# What Christians connected the Great Schism and Crab Nebula Supernova (1054 A.D.)?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, signs-of-the-times

What Christians connected the occurrence of the [Great Schism](http://newadvent.org/cathen/13535a.htm)* and the Crab Nebula Supernova, which both occurred around the middle of 1054 A.D.?

This question is not about Christians speculating in astrology—a form of divination, which is unlawful foreknowledge of future events.**

This question is related to how Christians have applied Genesis 1:14,

> …let them [i.e., the stars] be for signs…

to the 1054 supernova—namely, how they saw the supernova as a sign, not of a future event, but of, for example, God's displeasure at the [Great Schism](http://newadvent.org/cathen/13535a.htm).

---

<sup>* Also called the "Eastern Schism" or "East-West Schism"</sup>

<sup>** St. Thomas Aquinas defines astrology as when "one desires to foreknow the future that cannot be forecast by their [i.e., the stars'] means." ([*Summa Theologica* II-II q. 95 a. 5, "Whether divination by the stars is unlawful?"](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/summa/SS/SS095.html#SSQ95A5THEP1)). Basically, "to know with certitude future human actions" by means of the stars is unlawful because humans have freewill, which the influence of the stars cannot take away; "to foreknow those future things that are caused by heavenly bodies" is "neither an unlawful nor a superstitious divination." ([*ibid.*](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/summa/SS/SS095.html#SSQ95A5THEP1), *corpus*).</sup>

Comment: By "anyone else," do you mean users in this community or Christian historians?

Comment: I mean anybody!

Comment: This question probably won't be successful unless you can provide some background and ask a specific question about faith or practice within Christianity. As most Christians refrain from searching for significance in the stars, this is akin to asking a mathematician, "did anyone else make the connection between the big dipper and the polynomial (x -(0))*(x -(-1 + 5i))*(x - 4)*(x - (5 +5i))*(x - (10 + 5i))*(x -(8+ 7i))?" Astrology is not really relevant in Christianity.

Comment: @Andrew Really?  So why did the wise men follow the star which led to the Messiah?  And what does it mean in Genesis 1:14 "... and let them be for signs ..."?

Comment: But also, its a simple historic question.  If you don't know the answer, just ignore the question.

Comment: I think you need to show that someone would bother. Many things occur around the same time as something else. In fact, *everything* occurs around the same time as something else. Why should anybody connect *these two things*?

Comment: Really. "...most Christians refrain from searching for significance in the stars.." is far from an absolute statement about _signs_ in the stars. Believe me, I do not mean to quarrel. I am interested. I think it will be difficult to find someone who wrote the supernova in context of the schism, and unless you can ask about a specific author or group, this question probably won't get much attention. As for me, ignoring questions one doesn't know the answer to is a good way to ensure that one learns nothing, no? What sort of connection do you suppose someone may have made?

Comment: @fredsbend I think that perhaps the destruction of the star and dispersal of its matter is symbolic of the destruction of unity and scattering of its members. Read Revelation 1 and observe the stars acting as symbols of the church.

Comment: @Andrew I never hear respectable theologians talking about things like this. I never hear them connecting celestial events with Earth history. As you said before, Astrology is not really part of any Christian tradition. Revelation is rarely discussed in a context outside of itself, so that's not helpful either. The OP needs to show there there is a reasonable likelihood that someone would connect these two events. Otherwise, it's trivial.

Comment: @fredsbend People made connections between astronomical events and world events all the time.  For example, William the Conqueror used Halley's Comet to encourage his troops that they would be successful in their invasion of England.

Comment: @fredsbend I agree, even if someone _does_ connect them.

Comment: @Andrew The knowledge that a supernova is the destruction of a star would not have been known to anyone at that time.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Okay, excuse my ignorance. Those are the kinds of things that should be in your question, so people like me can see that there *is* a reasonable likelihood one would/should connect these events.

Comment: @fredsbend No, my suspicion is that you are looking at the question from your rather narrow perspective of what constitutes a respectable theologian.  I think that it is totally self-evident why this question is relevant.  And indeed Andrew's rather fine answer proves my point.

Comment: What time frame matters to you? Concurrent, as in from 1054 AD, or any time frame?

Comment: The open ended nature of my question shows that I am interested in ANY timeframe!

Comment: @curiousdannii right, which is why it may be a poignant and perhaps more complete symbol now, but then only a _sign of the time_, which is how I read the relevant text in Genesis 1.

Comment: How do you read the wise men following the star?  Why did they engage in astrology, and why did God reward their search?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Please be polite and respectful. We all can't know everything. The ball's in your court now. Make the question better or don't, from the suggestions of the three people who've commented. I no longer care at this point.

Comment: @fredsbend How am I being disrespectful?  I am merely answering your queries.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I said sorry for not knowing enough about this and suggested those things should be in your post to prevent confusion. Then you say "No, my suspicion is that you are looking at the question from your rather narrow perspective of what constitutes a respectable theologian." That came off as rude. This is also rude "If you don't know the answer, just ignore the question." If someone sees an issue with your question it is inappropriate to tell them to just go away then.

Comment: I've nominated to reopen.

Comment: @Geremia But I am also interested in anyone else who made such a connection, not just prominent theologians.  Let me illustrate with an example.  According to an admittedly rather bad Polish movie I saw on Netflix ("The Day of the Seige"), an Italian monk predicted the Siege of Vienna from observing the tale of Halley's comet in 1680.  Supposing there was some truth to this (that a well known monk made such a claim), could we consider that monk to be a prominent theologian?

Comment: Maybe this is a better place to ask: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/23480/did-anyone-connect-the-great-schism-and-crab-nebula-supernova-1054-a-d

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: I've removed the "prominent" qualifier. For this question to fair on this site, it seems we'll have to restrict it to theologians, not anyone (e.g., secular historians, et al.).

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I've never heard of that monk's prediction of the Siege of Vienna. If this question is reopened, I could answer more in detail whether and why such a prediction is sinful divination or a lawful reading of "the signs of the times." In short, if this monk claimed the comet _necessarily_ entailed the Siege of Vienna would occur, he was engaging in unlawful divination.

Comment: If this monk said the siege was a real _possibility_, he was likely noting that, as St. Thomas said ([*ibid.*](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/summa/SS/SS095.html#SSQ95A5THEP1) ad 2), "a great number of men follow their bodily passions, so that their actions are for the most part disposed in accordance with the inclination of the heavenly bodies: while there are few, namely, the wise alone, who moderate these inclinations by their reason. The result is that astrologers in many cases foretell the truth, especially in public occurrences which depend on the multitude," as did the Siege of Vienna.

Comment: @Geremia Thank you.  That is very interesting.  So how would Thomas Aquinas react to the wise men following the star to find Jesus?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Re: "How do you read the wise men..." They were magi, "wise men," that is _alchemists_.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Perhaps "Christians" is better than "theologians" or "anyone". That way the Bagdad Christian, Ibn Buṭlān, mentioned [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/23481/3202) could be an answer to this question.

Comment: So if God did orchestrate events so that the Crab Nebula was observed at the same time as the Schism, it wouldn't really be divination, would it?  It wouldn't predict future events - rather it could be interpreted as God expressing his opinion on his Church splitting.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Yes, that's what I meant when I said, in my edit of the question, "…how they saw the supernova as a sign, not of a future event, but of, for example, God's displeasure at the Great Schism."

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith The Magi used the stars (creation) to discover their cause (the Creator). (Creation is to God as effects are to their causes or signs are to the signified.)

Comment: Thank you, @Geremia.  Three things.  First: your remarks seem to rather perceptively describe my motivation in asking the question.  Second: however it was not my intention with this question to promote any kind of belief, merely to ask if other people had made a connection.  Third: the people on http://history.stackexchange.com/ also seem to have been bent out of shape with this question.  Since I wasn't promoting any kind of belief in the original question, I wonder if I have hit some raw nerve in peoples' psyche?

Comment: @Geremia The name of the monk was Marco d'Aviano.  I can find no online reference that suggests he connected Halley's comet with the Siege of Vienna.  But the movie "The Day of the Siege" http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1899285/ did provide this narrative.  I have no idea whether the script writer of the movie made this up, or whether he drew from some historical source (credible or otherwise).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Chicago Tribune](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/1994-07-17/features/9407170305_1_supernova-crab-nebula-astronomers) has an article that proposes some theories on why the observation of the supernova went mostly unnoticed in Europe. The article mentions the significance of the date with respect to the Church:

> Another reason the lack of records of the supernova is so puzzling is that 12 days after it first appeared in the sky, the Christian church began its final East-West split into the Roman Catholic and Eastern Orthodox Churches. Astronomical events were believed to foreshadow developments on Earth, making it unlikely that the appearance of a new star so near the time of such a major event would go unrecorded.

This source seems to imply that the contemporary sources who might have commented were silent on the matter.

The connection, however, has not been lost on *everyone*. This letter on [fivedoves.com](http://www.fivedoves.com/letters/may2011/mc513-2.htm) relates the two events intimately, though perhaps presumptuously:

> In heaven, the Great Schism of 1054 AD is marked by a supernova explosion creating the beautiful Crab Nebula and witnessed visually by both Chinese and European astronomers. The supernova appeared visible to the unaided human eye during daylight hours in July 1054 at approximately the same time as the eastern bishops voted to remove themselves from communion with the Roman Bishopric.

Comment: This is a great answer.  So why are you trashing the question?  (Also, how did you find the answer.  I tried various google combinations, and found nothing.)

Comment: I googled "crab nebula and the church". Personally I am interested in these sorts of things, but _for this site_ it's not a great question as asked.

Comment: That I got such a fine answer shows that this site is a great source for this kind of information.

Comment: I'm happy I could help!